# Multiple mail servers and reverse DNS

Tags: smtp, email-server, spf, reverse-dns

If I have three mail servers MS1, MS2 and MS3 all with different IPs but share the same domain name (exampledomain.com) and I use an SPF record to specify them, how would reverse DNS work on the server receiving mail from any of my mail servers since each of them would resolve to a different IP? 
Or would the receiving server have to check against the SPF records instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never name your mail servers (or any other server) with the naked domain name. This will break a lot more stuff than forward confirmed reverse DNS lookups.

Each server should have its own unique name which is a subdomain of your domain, and for which the reverse DNS points back to that name.

Comment: Ah I see, but if you used a subdomain, is there still a purpose of having a SPF record, since all it needs to say is which mail servers are permitted to send email on behalf of them?

Comment: @leeeennyy The SPF record says what servers can _send_ mail on behalf of your domain. If you intend to send mail, you should have one; if there is no SPF record it's assumed that you don't care who sends mail for your domain.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for clarifying this up/teaching me new things Michael!

Answer (score 3):

A configuration example for 3 Mailservers:

```
A Records
ms1.exampledomain.com => 125.1.1.1
ms2.exampledomain.com => 125.2.1.2
ms3.exampledomain.com => 125.3.1.3

PTR Records
125.1.1.1 => ms1.exampledomain.com
125.2.1.2 => ms2.exampledomain.com
125.3.1.3 => ms3.exampledomain.com

MX Records
exampledomain.com => ms1.exampledomain.com
exampledomain.com => ms2.exampledomain.com
exampledomain.com => ms3.exampledomain.com

TXT Records
exampledomain.com => "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

The spf have a relation with the mx records, every additional mail server in your domain mx records is allowed to send.

You can check if the configuration valid with one of this services

- https://mailtower.app
- https://emailaudit.com
- https://www.mail-tester.com

Comment: Hello, if I have two identical names for different IPs, when one is down will the other take over the service without problems?

A Records
smtp.exampledomain.com => 125.1.1.1
smtp.exampledomain.com => 125.2.1.2

Comment: No, this is wrong. Read again the answer you are commenting under, it shows up *correct* DNS setup. Also read the accepted answer: never have identical names for different mail servers. In mail, if you want takeover, make several MX records with different weights (these aren't shown; the least weight numerically will be tried first).